# Syncing documents between Ubuntu, Windows, external drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ntfs, rsync, exfat

I have been trying to set up a backup system which keeps my document files (Word docs, photos, music, videos, etc.) synced on my Windows and Ubuntu systems. You'd think it was easy, but I keep having problems. Can anyone help?

The idea is to have an identical set of all my document files in 3 places: 1/ Ubuntu, 2/ Windows, 3/external USB drive. It's not intended as an OS backup - I have something else in place for that.

My approach was this:

- Format external drive to exfat (I tried NTFS but kept getting problems, such as corrupt files)
- Periodically connect external drive to Ubuntu system and use rsync to mirror internal drive to external drive. Then use rsync again to mirror external drive to Ubuntu system (so now both Ubuntu drive and external drive should be identical)
- Likewise, periodically connect external drive to Windows system and use FreeFileSync to synchronise Windows internal drive and external drive

But... both rsync and FreeFileSync constantly throw up errors. Even more frustratingly rsync will copy certain source files time and time again despite being already on the destination drive. This is despite me setting flags to ignore file permissions/ownership.

Does anyone here have a similar set-up and a system that works?

Comment: You have not said how you are running your rsync (which options/parameters) or what errors you are getting which will make it very difficult for people to help. If you have not already you could try rsync with the `-c / --checksum` option which will ignore all dates/ownership and only look at file checksum. It's slow but perhaps more reliable over different machines where dates/ownership may change even if the file contents have not actually changed. May be too slow if you are syncing thousands of files.

Comment: FreeFileSync is fantastically stable. I'm using it on daily basis for about 8 years with "two way" mode. You have to setup folder-pair more carefully. Also you should have correct time and timezone on all your syncing devices.

Comment: I agree about FFS and like the simple design. Initially it seemed to work well. But now every time I run it I get errors saying "Cannot move file" referring to files with the ending ".ffs_tmp". I'm assuming these are some sort of log file, but can't work out how to stop the errors. Could it be anything to do with exfat file system? Or file permissions? Or the fact that I'm generating files in both Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: As regards rsync, I've tried quite a few different combinations of flags to get it to sync properly, each time trying to simplify and cut out things that could confuse it. My current iteration is just "sudo rsync -ruP [source] [destination]" but even that is causing problems.But again, could this be to do with mixing files from 2 different OSes? Or exfat?